# What are common interaction animations for error

Tags: mobile-application, error-message

Working on the error message system for checkout on an app. I've decided to use a simple skinny bar just below the main header to notify the user if something went wrong. however when it appears the rest of the content will get nudged down slightly. optionally if i want it to appear on top, some of the content of the screen it might cover other important information.

my question is what other options is there to put in the error message.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to avoid content nudging down and you also want it to appear at the top and for it to not cover other information, then why not use a blank placeholder space for when it is not visible.

When the error bar appears it can appear within the same space as this placeholder and no nudging will occur.

Message will have to be a fixed height though and therefore text wont be able to wrap. Therefore, you will need a way for the user to reveal more information, maybe you could offer an expand or popup?

Also the blank placeholder will take up space in the scrollview so you don't want it to be too tall.